# md5sum /dev/sdx

Tags: md5sum, cloning, ddrescue

I'm trying to make a clone of my SSD, which has Windows 7 installed. I've used `ddresuce`, and using md5sum as shown below. I'm trying to make an exact copy; how do I verify that it is an exact copy?

Also; is an exact copy necessary? I assume that `ddrescue` has done it's job, as the only file that exists is the image.

```
cd10d9e6a4983d7d02cea2aaae7c4fe0 /dev/sdx
a58a9c0d8370c005261794a30eb8ac9e image.img
```

Comment: Is there any chance `/dev/sdx` has been modified since `image.img` was created?  Have any partitions contained on the drive been mounted or `fsck`ed? Has the computer been rebooted? Does the drive contain a swap partition or boot partition or something that might be modified without notice?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232974/85039

Comment: I don't think there's any chance, but I'm also not sure.

Comment: Please visit this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048279/problems-modifying-lubuntu-iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ddrescue` is a reliable tool

When you clone with `ddrescue` from a drive, and all partitions in this source drive are unmounted and swapped off, the process is very robust, and you can expect to get an exact copy with all bytes in the cloned copy to match the original data.

The exception is if one of the drives (typically the source) has bad sectors, that cannot be read. `ddrescue` is better than most other tools to read damaged sectors, that are difficult to read, so it can copy more than other tools, often but not always every single byte (depending on the damage).

`ddrescue` can log the cloning process, and you can see in the log file, if there are any problems. If there is nothing in the log file about bad sectors, fine :-)

### Exact copy or not

An exact copy is [usually] not necessary, depending on what you intend to do with the cloned copy. One example is if you want to recover data from deleted files: then you need also free space to be copied, otherwise free space can be skipped (or zeroed) in the cloning process.

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) is a tool that skips free space in file systems and swap partitions. This makes it faster but the cloned copy or image is still useful. You can restore to a system, that behaves exactly like the original system (except for recovering data from deleted files).